# Form sending email on landing/refresh of website

Tags: php, html, forms, email, sendmail

My form is sending a blank email (field data empty) to me every time i visit my site or refresh it.

I had a look at a few posts mentioning 'Post/Redirect/Get', but that confused me more than helped, and im not sure if it pertains to my exact issue.

This was a basic responsive form i found online and had to find the PHP to actually send the form data. (Changing it to suit my needs)

I'm hoping there's just an error i've missed somewhere but i cant seem to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the basic form (minus css):

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "MY EMAIL HERE";
$subject = "Portfolio Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="/" method="post">
            <h3>Say Hello!</h3>
            <h4>Fill in the form below, and I'll get back to you as soon as i can. Thanks!</h4>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Name: (required)</span>
                    <input placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Email: (required)</span>
                    <input placeholder="Please enter your email address" type="text" name="email" tabindex="2" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Telephone: (required)</span>
                    <input placeholder="Please enter your number" type="text" name="phone" tabindex="3" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <span>Message: (required)</span>
                    <textarea placeholder="Include all the details you can" type="text" name="message" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Send Email</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `isset`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "MY EMAIL HERE";
$subject = "Portfolio Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
}
?>
```

it will `post` your email only when it submitted by any ..

Comment: Thanks very much: You were missing an extra ')' on the end of 'if(isset($_POST['submit'])' but it worked a treat. Appreciate your help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i have post this one for other in stackoverflow link [code link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379348/how-to-send-an-html-form-to-an-email/21379833#21379833)
this is my code.let try , i wish it will help you

```
<?PHP
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$to = "you@youremail.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

Email Address: $email";
$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: you@youremailaddress.com\n";
$usermessage = "Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list.";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
?>
```