# How to send an html form to an email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have this form:

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="mailto:dre4311@gmail.com">
    <p class="input-block">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" />
    </p>
    <p class="input-block">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *" />
    </p>
    <p class="input-block">
        <button class="button turquoise submit" type="submit" id="submit"><i class="icon-paper-plane-2"></i></button>
    </p>
 </form>
```

I would like to know, when people fill it how can I send the same filled details in the email?

Comment: You can do it with PROGRAMMING! Try it and let us know how you get on.

Comment: You need an SMTP server that will send your e-mail to a given address. You also need a way of communicating with that server, you can look into the `mail()` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?PHP
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$to = "you@youremail.com";
$subject = "New Email Address for Mailing List";
$headers = "From: $email\n";
$message = "A visitor to your site has sent the following email address to be added to your mailing list.\n

Email Address: $email";
$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";
$userheaders = "From: you@youremailaddress.com\n";
$usermessage = "Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list.";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
?>
```

i wish may it's will help you .

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Website: $website \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "YOUREMAIL@HERE.COM";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

Comment: This has to be the worst solution ever, but then again, the OP didn't bother to do any research, which is just as bad.

Comment: Why downvoted? I just told to try this method!

Comment: I actually upvoted you. Two other people downvoted.

Comment: You need to escape user input, do not include `$_POST` variables directly!